# Permanent delete row from database using datagridview

Tags: vb.net, winforms

In VB.net How to permanently delete a row from the database by selecting in the datagridview and using a button to delete

I tried to use DataGrid.Rows.Remove but it only deletes from the datagrid and not the database

I am using an SQL Server Database

Comment: Are you really using a DataGrid, not a DataGridView?  Is this Winforms?  How did the data get in the control?  Lots more information is needed

Comment: yeah sorry I am using datagridview

Comment: and it is win form

Comment: Then [edit] your post with the correct information.   As is, it misleads people to give wrong answers as with the one posted.  Make it easy for others to help you.  Also explain how the data got in the control

Comment: I dont understand what you mean by "control". I added the database from my SQL Server  in the project using Add Data Source

Comment: Your datagridview is a control as is a button or a listbox or any other object in your form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your original post and subsequent comments, I assume that your form looks something like

[image: Screenshot - Form with a DataGridView created using add DataSource]

If that is the case, you can permanently delete without adding code. The way this works is to allow you to edit, delete and add a number of rows. It has a backing dataset by default and this has change tracking capabilities. When you are done, you click the save icon and it will commit the changes to the database.

If you have added your own interface around that, you'll have to look at the generated controls for what to do. The method you used will create a backing `DataSet` and `DataAdapter` and `DataTable` amongst other items.

```
' You should have a binding source - I used a table called PointsOfInterest
Me.PointsOfInterestBindingSource.EndEdit()  ' changes that have been tracked will be applied to the datasource
Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.Your_DataSet)
```

That should commit your changes back to the database.

Comment: Thanks a lot fabulous. It solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Without more code this is difficult, but normally the grid is associated with a datasource.  The datasource has a property for deletequery.

Sample from [TechNet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.deletecommand(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2):

```
<%@Page  Language="VB" %>
<%@Import Namespace="System.Data.SqlClient" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<script runat="server">
 Sub On_Record_Deleting(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As SqlDataSourceCommandEventArgs)
     ' Cancel the delete operation if the checkbox is not checked.
     If Not CheckBox1.Checked 
            e.Cancel = True
            Label1.Text = "The command was cancelled because the CheckBox was not checked."
     End If

End Sub 'On_Record_Deleting

Sub On_Record_Deleted(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs)
    Label1.Text = e.AffectedRows & " row(s) were deleted"

End Sub

</script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
  <head runat="server">
    <title>ASP.NET Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

        <asp:SqlDataSource
            id="SqlDataSource1"
            runat="server"
            DataSourceMode="DataSet"
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyNorthwind%>"
            SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM Orders"
            DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Order Details] WHERE OrderID=@OrderID;DELETE FROM Orders WHERE OrderID=@OrderID;"
            OnDeleting="On_Record_Deleting"
            OnDeleted="On_Record_Deleted">
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
        <br />

       <asp:CheckBox 
         id="CheckBox1" 
         runat="server"
         autopostback="true"
         text="Check To Delete Data" />
        <br />
        <br />

        <asp:GridView
            id="GridView1"
            runat="server"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            DataKeyNames="OrderID"
            AutoGenerateDeleteButton="True"
            AllowPaging="True"
            PageSize="20"
            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Order ID" DataField="OrderID" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Customer" DataField="CustomerID" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Order Placed" DataField="OrderDate" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Order Shipped" DataField="ShippedDate" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>

        <asp:Label
            id="Label1"
            runat="server">
        </asp:Label>

    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: DataGridView is a WinForm control.

Comment: @Han DataSource control is common across web- and win-forms.  I can remove the source for the webgrid, but it just serves to show the implementation.